# Requests and webscraping: POST not returning expected results

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to retrieve the search results from [this booking website](https://www.booking.alilaurogruson.it/booking/services/datas).
I first make a `GET` request and with `BeautifulSoup` retrieve the `_csrf` needed for the `POST` request data. I then make the `POST` request passing the relevant data but instead of the search results, the trip selection form is returned again. What am I doing wrong?

```
token = get_csrf_token()
params = set_params(token)
res = get_request(params)

def get_csrf_token():
    url = 'https://www.booking.alilaurogruson.it/booking/services/datas'
    r = requests.get(url, verify=False, timeout=10)
    csrf = search_csrf_token(r)
    return csrf

def search_csrf_token(r):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
    csrf = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': '_csrf'})['value']
    return csrf

def set_params( csrf):
    params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
        "inputSearchFerriesBean.areasGoing": "1002",
        "inputSearchFerriesBean.tradesGoing": "12",
        "inputSearchFerriesBean.ret": "true",
        "inputSearchFerriesBean.areasReturn": "1007",
        "inputSearchFerriesBean.tradesReturn": "18",
        "inputSearchFerriesBean.dateGoing": "24/03/21",
        "inputSearchFerriesBean.dateReturn": "24/03/21",
        "_csrf": csrf
    })
    return params

def get_request(params):
    url = "https://www.booking.alilaurogruson.it/booking/services/search.action"
    r = requests.post(url, data=params, headers=headers, verify=False, timeout=10)
    return r
```

Comment: Try using selenium to scrape data

Comment: Thanks, but I want to try to make it work without using Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using session will help you reuse the cookies which play an important role here to fetch the required content. You don't need to encode params as requests module knows how to handle it.

Try this way instead:

```
import urllib
import urllib3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

def get_csrf_token(s):
    url = 'https://www.booking.alilaurogruson.it/booking/services/datas'
    r = s.get(url, verify=False, timeout=10)
    csrf = search_csrf_token(r)
    return csrf

def search_csrf_token(r):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
    csrf = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': '_csrf'})['value']
    return csrf

def set_params( csrf):
    params = {
        "inputSearchFerriesBean.areasGoing": "1002",
        "inputSearchFerriesBean.tradesGoing": "12",
        "inputSearchFerriesBean.ret": "true",
        "inputSearchFerriesBean.areasReturn": "1007",
        "inputSearchFerriesBean.tradesReturn": "18",
        "inputSearchFerriesBean.dateGoing": "24/03/21",
        "inputSearchFerriesBean.dateReturn": "24/03/21",
        "_csrf": csrf
    }
    return params

def get_request(s,params):
    url = "https://www.booking.alilaurogruson.it/booking/services/search.action"
    r = s.post(url, data=params, verify=False, timeout=10)
    return r


with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36'
    token = get_csrf_token(s)
    params = set_params(token)
    s.headers['Referer'] = 'https://www.booking.alilaurogruson.it/booking/services/datas'
    res = get_request(s,params)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    item = soup.select_one(".sectionTitle > span").text
    print(item)
```